# How to convert a Python data generator to a Tensorflow tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I have a data generator that I am producing training images from. I'd like to feed the data into the Tensorflow model by using this Python data generator, but I can't figure out how to convert the generator to a Tensorflow tensor. I'm looking for something similar to Keras' fit_generator() function.

Thanks!

Comment: what specifically is there error? and what have you tried. fit_generator take a _generator_ as argument, why would you need anything else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) method provides a way to convert Python generators into `tf.Tensor` objects that evaluate to each successive element from the generator.

Let's say you have a simple generator that generates tuples (but could alternatively generate lists or NumPy arrays):

```
def g():
  yield 1, 10.0, "foo"
  yield 2, 20.0, "bar"
  yield 3, 30.0, "baz"
```

You can use the `tf.data` API to convert the generator first to a `tf.data.Dataset`, then to a `tf.data.Iterator`, and finally to a tuple of `tf.Tensor` objects.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(g, (tf.int32, tf.float32, tf.string))

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

int_tensor, float_tensor, str_tensor = iterator.get_next()
```

You can then use `int_tensor`, `float_tensor`, and `str_tensor` as the inputs to your TensorFlow model. See the [`tf.data` programmer's guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) for more ideas.

Comment: What would be the tf type corresponding to image data (imageio.core.util.Image) of a component from the generator's yield (next)? Is there such tf.image?

Comment: Hi, @mrry, im wondering that whether can i use tf.data.Dataset.from_generator to with python generator that will yield (single image),(python_list)?

Comment: This is TF1 code, which requires `tf.compat.v1.data.Dataset.from_generator` to run in TF2. I'm sure TF2 has some better solution, but that's what I'm using so far

Comment: Actually, it seems the TensorFlow 2 solution is simply replacing
`iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()`
with
`iterator = iter(dataset)`